# How can I ask for permissions using Facebooker2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebooker2

I need to prompt user for permissions when they first time use the application.
I am using facebooker2 along with Mogli 
I am using rails 3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should include a perms parameter in your login helper:

```
<%= fb_login_and_redirect('<your URL here>', :perms => 'email,user_birthday') %>
```